# Rails Where vs Join vs Union

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Having trouble with my activerecord searches. I thought I had my models setup correctly, but I’m poor with my joins (not sure if a join or union is the correct way to go? It shouldn’t be this difficult).

I have guides creating bids on trips that have start_dates. I want to create a list of bids that have expired (ie. the start date is in the past). Guides can also have LosingBids if a bid has been declined

In a perfect world I would have one resultset that includes both losing bids and expired bids for that guide, but I’m find with 2 different result sets. Unfortunately I can’t get any of the “expired bids” to work. Results/errors in the comments of the code.

```
class GuidesController < ApplicationController

  def expired_declined

    #this declined_bids call works
    @declined_bids = LosingBid.where("guide_id = ?", current_guide.id.to_s)

    #this expired_bids call returns Trips, not Bids
    @expired_bids = Bid.where("guide_id = ?", current_guide.id.to_s).expired

    #this expired_bids call gives me the following error:
    #SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: trips.start_date: SELECT  1 AS one FROM #”bids" WHERE (guide_id = '1') AND (trips.start_date < '2018-05-30') LIMIT ?
    @expired_bids = Bid.where("guide_id = ?", current_guide.id.to_s).where("trips.start_date < ?", Date.today)
  end
end

class Guide < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids
  has_many :losing_bids
end

class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids
end

class Bid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :guide

  def self.expired
    Trip.where("start_date <= ?", Date.today) #.where("guide_id = ?", current_guide.id.to_s)
  end
end

class LosingBid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :guide
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trip.where("start_date <= ?", Date.today).bids` will return you the expired bids.

You should move the `expired` scope in the Trip, rather than on the Bid.

If you want a scope on Bid you can define.

```
class Bid
  scope :expired, -> { joins(:trip).where('trips.start_date <= ?', Date.current) }
end
```

Comment: You should use `Date.current` instead of `Date.today` as the later does not properly take the timezone into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I would really question if you need to have a separate `LosingBid` model or if its just creating duplication and unnecessary complexity. Instead just add an [enum column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to bids which contains the status:

```
class Bid
  enum status: [:pending, :declined, :expired, :accepted]
end
```

This is just a simple integer column that acts as a bit mask.

This will simply let you query by:

```
Bid.pending
Bid.expired
Bid.where(status: [:pending, :accepted])
Bid.where.not(status: :accepted)
```

You can simply reject a bid by:

```
class BidsController
  # PATCH /bids/decline
  def reject
    @bid.declined!
    redirect_to bid, notice: 'Bid declined'
  end
end
```

You could then setup scheduled task which runs once per day to automatically expire tasks (example with the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem):

```
every 1.days do
  runner "BidExpiryService.perform"
end
```

---

```
# app/services/bid_expiry_service.rb
module BidExpiryService
  def self.perform
    bids = Bid.pending
              .joins(:trip)
              .where('trips.start_date <= ?', Date.current)
    bids.update_all(status: Bid.statuses[:expired])
    # @todo notify guides that bid has expired
  end
end
```

Comment: this is really great, i had been debating back and forth in my mind if it's better to move the "declined" bids to a separate table to keep the tables from getting bloated, but it seems like then this would be the preferred way to go about it? my background is in php but i'm not a professional programmer (its a side project) so i'm not clear on the best practices for data storage/retrieval.

Comment: I would say that the benefits of being able to query it as a homogenous collection outweighs the "table bloat" (which may actually really just be premature optimisation).